# I can't add current location to Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps, currentlocation

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView: GMSMapView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XYZ")

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.621262,longitude: -122.378945, zoom: 12)
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

    }
}
```

What should I add to this code?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do or at least what you want and what are the issue you are facing.

Comment: Refer this : http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This should help you,Please check.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView: GMSMapView?


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XYZ")
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.621262,longitude: -122.378945, zoom: 12)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.init(), camera: camera)
        // Below line is to default show user current location(Bue dot with circular accuracy radius around it)
        mapView!.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        view = mapView
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.